# nt6 hdd installer 3.14 not working on win10

Tags: windows-10

When I run nt6 hdd installer on my win10 pc, it showed a window like this and disappeared within 2-3 seconds.

[image]

Can you help me in resolving it?

Comment: What's the nt6 hdd installer version? I suggest that try to use the latest version. Also prepare Win10 ISO files to be unzipped to the root of any disk other than the C disk .